Error Checking in a Bit Sequence Using Parity Bit Verification (Assembly x86)
Given a bit sequence, knowing that every n bits (of data) there is a parity bit (1 if the number of bits set to 1 among the previous n is odd), check for errors. N.B.
• The length in bits is specified as input: it may happen that the last BYTE of the array is only partially used.
• It can be assumed that the length of the bit sequence is always a multiple of (n+1).
• The bits within a BYTE should be analyzed from the least significant to the most significant.
Input: an array of BYTES (considered as a bit sequence),
a DWORD (the length of the bit sequence), a BYTE (the value of n).
Output: a BYTE (containing 1 if there are errors, otherwise 0). I tried to write this, in some cases work but in others like with the given input it doesn't.
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    // Input
    unsigned char vet[] = { 0xAD,0xDC };  // Test array
    unsigned int len = 16;  // Length (number of bits)
    unsigned char n = 15;   // Number of data bits

    // Output
    unsigned char errors = 0;  // 1 = errors; 0 = no errors

    __asm {
        XOR ECX, ECX                 // ECX serves as a bit counter
        LEA ESI, vet                 // ESI points to the beginning of the array
        MOV EBX, len                 // EBX contains the length of the bit sequence
        MOV AL, n                    // AL contains the value of n (number of data bits)
        ADD AL, 1                    // Increment AL to include the parity bit
        XOR EDX, EDX                 // EDX will be used for counting bits set to 1

        check_next_bit:
        CMP ECX, EBX                 // Compare the counter with the sequence length
        JGE done_checking            // If the counter is greater or equal, finish

        MOV EDI, ECX                 // EDI is the current index
        SHR EDI, 3                   // Divide by 8 to find the correct byte
        MOVZX EAX, BYTE PTR[ESI + EDI] // Load the current byte into EAX

        MOV EDI, ECX
        AND EDI, 7                   // Get the position of the bit within the byte
        SHR EAX, CL                  // Shift right to get the required bit
        AND EAX, 1                   // Isolate the least significant bit

        CMP CL, n                    // Compare the counter with n (number of data bits)
        JE check_parity              // If equal, check the parity

        ADD EDX, EAX                 // Add the current bit to EDX
        INC CL                       // Increment the bit counter
        JMP check_next_bit           // Repeat the cycle for the next bit

        check_parity:
        AND EDX, 1                   // Calculate the parity
        CMP EDX, EAX                 // Compare the calculated parity with the expected parity bit
        JNE set_error                // If they don't match, set the error flag

        XOR EDX, EDX                 // Reset the count of bits set to 1
        INC CL                       // Increment the bit counter
        JMP check_next_bit           // Repeat the cycle for the next bit

        set_error:
        MOV errors, 1                // Set the error flag
        JMP done_checking            // Finish the checking

        done_checking:
    }

    // Output to screen
    printf("The bit sequence %scontains errors\n", (errors ? "" : "does not "));
}


I noticed that the Assembly code doesn't handle the parity bit correctly. It should check if the parity bit matches the calculation of the parity of the preceding bits, but it seems that the current implementation doesn't work as expected.

Is it part of your assignment to use assembly? Otherwise just don't use it. If you write simple, clean and maintainable C code, it's likely that the compiler will be able to optimize it much better than any of us can.

yes unfortunately is part of my assignment to use assembly

It might still be a good idea to code it in C first, and make sure you have something that works. Then translate that C code into assembler.

As long as n+1 bits fit into a register, you can use the PF flag of the x86 CPU with no need to manually compute any parity yourself. For larger n you need a bit more trickery.

Addendum regarding the parity flag: It seems this only takes the least significant byte of the result into account. So it is a bit more complicated. But you can xor together multiple bytes and then use the PF after the last xor operation.

How does it not work? Use your debugger to single step and see where it goes wrong. You did AND EDI, 7 but then did not use that for the SHR. You could for example AND ECX, 7 and after the shift MOV ECX, EDI to restore ECX.

Also since you keep incrementing ECX the CMP CL, n will only work once.

For this kind of task you need to develop an input code that can operate independently from the rest of the code. The below 'bit fetcher' uses its own set of registers EAX, ESI, and EDI and outputs a single bit via the carry flag.
 xor   ebx, ebx
 xor   esi, esi     ; Offset within the source array
 xor   edi, edi     ; Counts number of cached (in AL) source bits

 mov   ecx, len     ; ECX is outer loop counter (len) using step (n + 1)
OuterLoop:
 mov   bl, n
 inc   ebx          ; EBX is inner loop counter (n + 1) using step (1)
 sub   ecx, ebx     ; Outer loop step is taken early
 xor   edx, edx     ; Counts number of ON bits
InnerLoop:

 test  edi, edi                  ; 'bit fetcher'     \
 jnz   GetOneBit                                      | This code operates
 add   edi, 8                                         | asynchronous to
 movzx eax, byte ptr [vet + esi] ; Read one byte      | the loops around it
 inc   esi                       ; and cache it in AL |
GetOneBit:                                            | It would be nice to keep
 dec   edi                       ; Consume one bit    | this in a subroutine
 shr   eax, 1                    ; from AL -> CF     /

 adc   edx, 0
 dec   ebx
 jnz   InnerLoop
 and   edx, 1       ; If bit 0 is ON, then there's a mismatch between
 jnz   Done         ; Error EDX=1     calculated and stored parity bit
 test  ecx, ecx     ; (*)
 jnz   OuterLoop
Done:
 mov   errors, dl   ; DL=[0,1]

(*) No need to look out for incomplete records given that the task description states; "It can be assumed that the length of the bit sequence is always a multiple of (n+1)."

thank you so much for your contribute (the problem is solved)
